# How to correctly use Sphinx sidebar options "globaltoc.html" to generate a collapsible menu tree

Tags: python-sphinx, sidebar

I resorted to using option `html_sidebars` template **globaltoc.html** to get a multi-level menu tree something as this:

```
1. Execution
    1.1. Activities
        1.1.1. Report
        1.1.2. Follow up
```

By creating source files (**.rst**), I am able to build up the above scenario. On clicking the parent node **Execution**, the sub-nodes below all expand simultaneously. Later I added two more files, designed to be added at the end of last node. So the new menu tree looks like this:

```
1. Execution
    1.1. Activities
        1.1.1. Report
        1.1.2. Follow up
        1.1.3. Escalation
        1.1.4. Final Submission
```

Now something peculiar is happening. When the top node **Execution** is clicked all the sub-nodes, including the newly added ones (**1.1.3** and **1.1.4**), expand at the same time (as I think they should be doing). However, when one of the older nodes, say, **1.1.1. Report** is clicked, the new nodes **1.1.3** and **1.1.4** collapse. And to open the the new pages, I have to click on the top node **1. Execution** to make the newer nodes visible again (so that these may be clicked to navigate to the doc).

I have run `make clean html` but situation has remained to same.

**My question is:** Am I correct in using **globaltoc.html** to build a collapsible menu tree in the sidebar. And if yes, what should be done to get the behavior (collapse/expand) right.

Comment: Which Sphinx theme are you using? You should consult its documentation first.

Comment: I am using the **classic** theme. Anyway, I discovered that once a new node is added, the earlier additions (**1.1.3** and **1.1.4**) start to work normally.....and leave its fallibilities at the door of the latest node!! Could not locate documentation on themes excepting what is there on Sphinx official [site](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/theming.html#builtin-themes).

Answer (score 0):

See the [`-a` sphinx-build option](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/man/sphinx-build.html#cmdoption-sphinx-build-a).

> If given, always write all output files. The default is to only write output files for new and changed source files. (This may not apply to all builders.)

Alternatively `make clean`, then `make html` would have the same result.